# How can i disable some of the legend at livechart?

Tags: wpf, graph, border, legend

I am using live-chart to plot some series. I also want to add a border to chart area so I added it as a new series. but when I want to show the legend of the main series the legend of border will be appear at chart. Is there any solution to disable this specific legend?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the visibility of a series by changing the `Visibility` Attribute
e.g:

```
series.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

Not sure If that already solves your problem, since  I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. You can also change the z index of a series by using the `SetZIndex` Method
e.g:

```
System.Windows.Controls.Panel.SetZIndex(series, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you Victor.
It seems that I could not state my problem correctly.
Actually the main problem is that I could not add a border around the chart area explicitly by live charts.
Because of that i decided to add a border to the chart by defining it as  a closed line.
When I enable the legend of chart, the legend of the border is also appeared at legend box.
Is there any easier solution to add border to chart area at live charts?
Is there any solution to disable only the visibility of the legend of border while the legend of other graph are visibel?
Best regards